# Nextjs 14 handling server action error An error occurred in the Server Components render

Tags: next.js

[image]

[image]

[image]

`Sorry about images stackoverflow bugged out and doesn't allow 4 spaces or 2 spaces but this does seem to work lol`

It works great in dev then when its built and served nextjs just returns

An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details.

How am I supposed to handle @tanstack/react-query errors?

Tried setting global error tsx file and error tsx file but nextjs isn't catching it properly

Comment: Next time log errors within your server component so you can see error messages inside terminal. Also, don't use images when posting here. It makes it harder to follow and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with this

```
export const getAllUsers = async () => {
  // todo users interface data type once we build all models
  let data: any = [];
  try {
    const rateLimiter = await getRateLimiter();
    await rateLimiter.consume(await getIPAddress());
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      data,
      success: false,
      message: "Too many requests",
      status: 429,
    };
  }
  try {
    const allUsers = await db.select().from(users);
    data = allUsers;
    return {
      data,
      success: true,
      message: GENERIC_SUCCESS,
      status: 200,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      data,
      success: false,
      message: GENERIC_ERROR,
      status: 500,
    };
  }
};
```